# React - Maximum update depth exceeded when setting state in use effect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, use-effect

So in my database there are incoming calls, outgoing calls, meetings and emails. In this component, I want to get all of them and combine them into one array to fill my datatable and create a "latest activity" table. I have fetched each type from my redux store and have a useEffect for each to append it to the data that fills the datatable. It all works fine and I get the result I want however the error in the title appears and turns my page into a vegetable afterwards.

```
const [incomingCalls, setIncomingCalls] = useState([])
    const [outgoingCalls, setOutgoingCalls] = useState([])
    const [meetings, setMeetings] = useState([])
    const [emails, setEmails] = useState([])

    const [showIncoming, setShowIncoming] = useState(false);
    const [showId, setShowId] = useState('')

    const [data, setData] = useState([...incomingCalls])

    const incomingCallList = useSelector((state) => state.incomingCallList);
    const {
        loading: loadingCalls,
        error: errorIncCalls,
        incomingCalls: incCalls,
    } = incomingCallList;

    const outgoingCallList = useSelector((state) => state.outgoingCallList);
    const {
        loading: loadingOutCalls,
        error: errorOutCalls,
        outgoingCalls: outCalls,
    } = outgoingCallList;

    const meetingList = useSelector((state) => state.meetingList);
    const {
        loading: loadingMeetings,
        error: errorMeetings,
        meetings: meetings_list,
    } = meetingList;

    const emailList = useSelector((state) => state.emailList);
    const {
        loading: loadingEmails,
        error: errorEmails,
        emails: email_list,
    } = emailList;

    useEffect(() => {
        if(props.contractor._id) {
            dispatch(listIncomingCalls())
            dispatch(listOutgoingCalls())
            dispatch(listMeetings())
            dispatch(listEmails())
        }
    }, [props.contractor._id, dispatch])

    const showIncomingModalHandler = id => {
        console.log(id)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if(incCalls) {
            const transformedIncomingCalls = incCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Incoming Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: c.time_created,
                link: <Button onClick={() => showIncomingModalHandler(c._id)}><Eye /></Button>
            }))
            setIncomingCalls(transformedIncomingCalls)
            setData([...incomingCalls])
        }
    }, [incCalls, incomingCalls, props.contractor._id])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(outCalls) {
            const transformedOutgoingCalls = outCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Outgoing Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: c.time_created,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/outgoing-calls/${c._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setOutgoingCalls(transformedOutgoingCalls)
            setData([...incomingCalls, ...outgoingCalls])
        }
    }, [outCalls, incomingCalls, outgoingCalls, props.contractor._id])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(meetings_list) {
            const transformedMeetings = meetings_list.filter(meeting => meeting.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(m => ({
                type: 'Meeting',
                contact_person: m.held_with,
                logged_by: m.logged_by.name,
                date: m.meeting_time,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/meeting/${m._id}`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setMeetings(transformedMeetings)
            setData([...incomingCalls, ...outgoingCalls, ...meetings])
        }
    }, [meetings_list, incomingCalls, outgoingCalls, meetings, props.contractor._id])

    useEffect(() => {
        if(email_list) {
            const transformedEmails = email_list.filter(email => email.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(e => ({
                type: 'Email',
                contact_person: e.contact_person,
                logged_by: e.logged_by.name,
                date: e.date,
                link: <> <LinkContainer to={`/emails/${e.contractor._id}/`} className='text-success' style={{ cursor: 'pointer'}}><Eye /></LinkContainer> </>
            }))
            setEmails(transformedEmails)
            setData([...incomingCalls, ...outgoingCalls, ...meetings, ...emails])
        }
    }, [email_list, incomingCalls, outgoingCalls, meetings, emails, props.contractor._id])

    const columns = [
        { name: 'Action', selector: 'link', sortable: true },
        { name: 'Activity Type', selector: 'type', sortable: true },
        { name: 'Contact Person', selector: 'contact_person', sortable: true },
        { name: 'Logged By', selector: 'logged_by', sortable: true },
        { name: 'Date', selector: 'date', sortable: true }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values which you try to pass in the dependency array of react has to be primitive . It should not be array or object.

For example, consider this useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
        if(incCalls) {
            const transformedIncomingCalls = incCalls.filter(call => call.contractor._id === props.contractor._id).map(c => ({
                type: 'Incoming Call',
                contact_person: c.contact_person,
                logged_by: c.created_by.name,
                date: c.time_created,
                link: <Button onClick={() => showIncomingModalHandler(c._id)}><Eye /></Button>
            }))
            setIncomingCalls(transformedIncomingCalls)
            setData([...incomingCalls])
        }
    }, [incCalls, incomingCalls, props.contractor._id])
```

when this useEffect runs you are setting the state with

```
 setIncomingCalls(transformedIncomingCalls)
 setData([...incomingCalls])
```

Once there is state update your entire function will re-run. Now in your code you have this

```
  const {
        loading: loadingCalls,
        error: errorIncCalls,
        incomingCalls: incCalls,
    } = incomingCallList;
```

Now for every re-render you are creating a new incCalls which is array. So when you are passing a dependency as an array react does shallow comparison. It checks whether the previous reference of this array is same as the new one ? . But here it is not because the reference changes each time for every re-render . So your useEffect will run again and this leads to infinite re-render and the maximum stack exceeded error.

Avoid passing arrays or objects as a dependency in the array. You can modify your dependency array as below . This will trigger the useEffect only when the length of inCalls or incoming is changed

```
[incCalls.length, incomingCalls.length, props.contractor._id]
```

Comment: Hi, I understand why it is looping now thank you for the explanation, however when i try the suggested dependency array I get the error `Cannot read property length of undefined`

Comment: what is your initial value for `incCalls` and `incomingCalls`

Comment: Both are an empty array

Comment: If i am not wrong there is nothing in your code called as `incomingCalls` . Because you have aliased it to be `incomingCalls : incCalls` . So you can't use `incomingCalls`  anymore in your code now . where ever you have `incomingCalls` you should reference it with `incCalls`

Comment: incomingCalls is the name of the state variable at the very first line. incCalls has many more fields than I need, so thats why i process them in the map function and set it as incomingCalls. I do the same for outgoingCalls, meetings and emails. Then set my data as all of them combined

Comment: Then you need to check whether you are getting a value other than Array when you are doing some interactions .

Comment: I will completely re-do the code because I think having them all as separate state variables is unnecessary